# backslash in a character set of a python regexp (how to specify 'not a backslash' character set)?

Tags: python, regex

I want to use a python regexp to remove the comments in a LaTeX file. In LaTeX a comment starts by "%". But if the % character is escaped ("\%") then its not a comment, its the symbol percent.

This task is just one among many regexp that I apply on my LaTeX text. I store all these reg exp in a list of dicts.

The problem I face is that the regexp I use for pruning the comments does not work (because I do not know how to specify the character set 'not backslash'). The backslash in the character set escapes the closing ']' and the regexp is incorrect.

My code:

```
regexps=[]
regexps.append({r'left':'%.*', 'right':r''}) # this strips all the comments, but messes up with the percent characters (\%)
regexps.append({r'left':'[^\]%.*', 'right':r''}) # this is incorrect (escapes the closing "]" )
return applyRegexps(latexText, regexps)


def applyRegexps(text, listRegExp):
    """ Applies successively many regexps to a text"""
    if testMode:
        print str(listRegExp)
    # apply all the regexps in the list
    for element in listRegExp:
        left = element['left']
        right = element['right']
        r=re.compile(left)
        text=r.sub(right,text)
    return text
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Gilles

Comment: Did you try to use `r'[^\\]'`? The `\\` should the regex syntax for escaping the backslash

Comment: If you want to put a literal backslash into a regex, double it. Your patter should read '[^\\]%.*'

Comment: Thanks guys, Martijn Pieters answers works. I must be tired...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply double the backslash, but do use a raw string literal to avoid having to double them *again*:

```
regexps.append({'left':r'[^\\]%.*', 'right':r''})
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Martijn Pieters's answer is the one you asked for, I am not sure that this is what you are really looking for. For example this pattern will not match a `%` as the very first character of the string (because there is no non-backslash character in front of it). What you actually want is probably a negative lookahead (you still need to escape the backslash):

```
r'(?<!\\)%.*'
```

The difference is this:

- `[^\\]%` matches a `%` preceded by a non-backslash character (including that character in the match)
- `(?<!\\)%` matches a `%` that is not preceded by a backslash character (without including it in the match)

The latter one is also true for `%` at the beginning of the string.